# How to avoid this repetitive CASE WHEN pattern in postgres query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have this postgres query that is validating if the columns are null or not based on one codition, this is a normal query that is not requiring function, could be overkill a functional approach because this is unique scenario in the collection.

The query is working as expected but I want to shrink the logic if is possible.

```
CASE WHEN LOWER(COALESCE(users.user_number, users.customer_number)) LIKE 'vip%' THEN NULL
    ELSE COALESCE(users.user_badge, users.customer_badge) END                              AS normal_badge,
CASE WHEN LOWER(COALESCE(users.user_number, users.customer_number)) LIKE 'vip%' THEN NULL
    ELSE users.expiration_date END                                                         AS expiration_date,
CASE WHEN LOWER(COALESCE(users.user_number, users.customer_number)) LIKE 'vip%' THEN NULL
    ELSE COALESCE(users.user_number, users.customer_number) END                            AS standard_user,
```

Comment: You can"t, as you want three columns

Comment: Is your query fetching data from other tables too? Paste your entire query.

Comment: It would help to normalise your schema. Right now it seems like instead of pulling out the vip info to an `is_vip` boolean column, you're extracting that from not just another field that already holds other info, but looking for it in two alternative ones.

Comment: The best optimization depends on the full query and on the universe around it. *<todo: insert the sound of a zen gong bonked in distance, [toss beard to the side](https://c.tenor.com/3g4vHlBUEK8AAAAd/tenor.gif), absently stare into the horizon nodding>*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using CTE:

```
WITH user_data AS (
    SELECT *,
           LOWER(COALESCE(user_number, customer_number)) AS lower_number
    FROM users
)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN lower_number LIKE 'vip%' THEN NULL
         ELSE COALESCE(user_badge, customer_badge) 
    END AS normal_badge,
    CASE WHEN lower_number LIKE 'vip%' THEN NULL
         ELSE expiration_date 
    END AS expiration_date,
    CASE WHEN lower_number LIKE 'vip%' THEN NULL
         ELSE COALESCE(user_number, customer_number) 
    END AS coalesced_number
FROM user_data;
```

Comment: either CTE, or SELECT from a sub-select ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can pull the information out to a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) or consider storing it in a separate one in the first place: [Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vrIOHvcM)

```sql
alter table users add column is_vip boolean generated always as 
(COALESCE(users.user_number,users.customer_number,'') ILIKE 'vip%') stored;
```

Note that you can use [`ilike`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) instead of `lower() like lower()` to make it case-insensitive.

If you flip the check in your `case when (condition) then null else (field) end` construct, you can save a few characters. `case when not(condition)then(field)end` achieves the same because a missing `else` leads to `null`.

```sql
case when not is_vip then COALESCE(users.user_badge, users.customer_badge) end AS normal_badge,
case when not is_vip then users.expiration_date end AS expiration_date,
case when not is_vip then COALESCE(users.user_number, users.customer_number) end
```

You can also attach sets of fields with a [`left join lateral`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL), all of which you nullify at once using a single join condition:

```sql
select * from users
left join lateral(
  select COALESCE(users.user_badge, users.customer_badge) as normal_badge,
         users.expiration_date,
         COALESCE(users.user_number, users.customer_number) as normal_number
) on not is_vip;
```

```sql
select * from users
left join lateral(
  select COALESCE(users.user_badge, users.customer_badge) as normal_badge,
         users.expiration_date,
         COALESCE(users.user_number, users.customer_number) as normal_number
) on not (COALESCE(users.user_number,users.customer_number,'') ILIKE 'vip%');
```

Note that in all cases, if you don't have `vip` prefix in non-null `user_number`, but you do in `customer_number`, the user isn't considered `vip`: `coalesce()` picks and check only the first one.

Answer (score 1):

A `LEFT JOIN` can use a single join condition to nullify multiple columns at once, like [Zegarek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5298879/zegarek) already provided.

My shortest version:

```sql
SELECT x.*
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT COALESCE(u.user_badge, u.customer_badge)
        , u.expiration_date
        , COALESCE(u.user_number, u.customer_number)
   ) x(normal_badge, expiration_date, standard_user)
       ON lower(COALESCE(u.user_number, u.customer_number)) ^@ 'vip' IS NOT TRUE;
```

Note that we cannot simply invert the condition with `NOT`. That would fail if  `user_number` and `customer_number` are both `null`. While that is a possibility, use the null-safe `IS NOT TRUE`.

About the "starts with" operator `^@`:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)